# CodeBlocks "Other Linker Options" Translation "Link Libraries" and Library Inclusion Efficiency

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I find myself doing a lot of library including and juggling in recent projects with code::blocks- and I'm looking to improve my efficiency.

Currently, since I'm doing work with curl, zlib, wxwidgets, and other libraries, it takes quite some time to append the list after the initial project creation (even if I used a template).

Here's quick peek at a working project with all of the library files and how I'm including them:

[image: List Of Library Inclusions in "Link Libaries"]

**Now to the two part question:**

1. How can I quickly add several library files at once, *in the correct order?* (the order is evidently quite important)
2. How do .a files translate into "other linker options", in other words, can I simply include the search directory and use something like `lwxmsw32u_core` instead of including `...>\libwxmsw32u_core.a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so there's a simple solution, the project file for code::blocks is quite mundane, a light XML implementation- you can very easily copy libraries (in the correct order) from one project to another by editing the plain text of the .cbp file.

[image: Notepad++ of CBP file]